# Problem on parallel transport

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I've been trying to go through an example for parallel transport but I cannot quite follow the solution.

*A surface (paraboloid) is given by the parametric equation $r(ρ, φ)$ = $ρ \cos(φ)\hat{i}$ +
$ρ \sin(φ)\hat{j}$ + $aρ^2\hat{k}$ where a is a constant. Evaluate the metric and Christoffel symbols
in the (ρ, φ) coordinates. A unit vector X initially pointing along $e_φ$ is parallel
transported along the curve given by ρ = R, φ = 2πt for 0 ≤ t ≤ 1. What is the angle
between the initial X(t = 0) and final X(t = 1) vectors?*

I've found the metric: 
$g_{ρρ} = 1+4a^2ρ^2$, $g_{φφ} = ρ^2$, $g_{φρ} = 0$ and the Christoffel symbols
$\Gamma^ρ_{ρρ}=\frac{4a^2ρ}{1+4a^2ρ^2}$,
$\Gamma^ρ_{φφ}=\frac{-ρ}{1+4a^2ρ^2}$,
$\Gamma^φ_{φρ}=\Gamma^φ_{ρφ}=\frac{1}{ρ}$.

Now using the parallel transport equation, $\dot{X^a} + \Gamma^a_{bc}X^b\dot{x^c} = 0$, I get

$\dot{X^ρ} - \frac{R}{1+4a^2R^2}X^φ\dot{φ}+ \frac{4a^2R}{1+4a^2R^2}X^ρ\dot{ρ} = 0$ and
$\dot{X^φ} + \frac{1}{R}X^ρ\dot{φ} + \frac{1}{R}X^φ\dot{ρ}= 0$

Then I am not sure how to proceed - any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: As written this is a pure differential geometry question, not a physics question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind - Sounds a little narrow. Clearly this is the math used in GR, and is no doubt motivated by GR homework. It is physics in spirit.

Comment: @mmesser314 It's still closable as a homework question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a differential geometry question, though you find this in general relativity.

Here the key is to use what you have: $\rho=R$ and $\phi=2\pi t$, i.e. $\dot{\rho}=0$ and $\dot{\phi}=2\pi$. Then you should be able to simplify and obtain two equations:
\begin{equation}\dot{X}^{\rho}-\frac{2\pi R}{1+4a^{2}R^{2}}X^{\varphi}=0\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\dot{X}^{\varphi}+\frac{2\pi}{R}X^{\rho}=0\end{equation}

From here, you can differentiate the first equation and substitute the second one to obtain a differential equation for $X^{\rho}$, and differentiate the second one and substitute into the first one to obtain the other differential equation for $X^{\varphi}$. Solve them and you are done. Here I am assuming your metric and Christoffel symbols are correct, but the idea remains.